# Polar form of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

Question:
Write the polar form of $$\frac{(1+i)^{13}}{(1-i)^7}$$

Well its obviously impractical to expand it and try and solve it.
Multiplying the denominator by $(1+i)^7$ will simplify the denominator, and a single term in the numerator.

Answer I got:
$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(cos(\frac{\pi}{4}) + sin(\frac{\pi}{4})i)^{20}$$

Is this correct?

Comment: I believe your answer is wrong. Just using the lengths of those numbers you get the length of the answer should be $(\sqrt2)^{13}/(\sqrt2)^7 = (\sqrt2)^6 = 8$.

Comment: Don't ever expand. Immediately convert $1+i$ and $1-i$ into polar form and go from there.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's not correct. You must have made a couple of errors in your expansions.
\begin{align}
  \frac{(1+i)^{13}}{(1-i)^7} &= \frac{(1+i)^{13}(1+i)^7}{(1-i)^7(1+i)^7} \\
      &= \frac{1}{2^7}(1+i)^{20} \\
      &= \frac{1}{2^7}\left(\sqrt{2}\left(\cos\frac{\pi}{4} + i \sin\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\right)^{20} \\
      &= \frac{2^{10}}{2^7}\left(e^{i\pi/4}\right)^{20} \\
      &= 8e^{5\pi i} \\
      &= -8.
\end{align}
The polar form is $8(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)$, or $(8,\pi)$.

Comment: But that's not the polar form? Isn't polar form with $cos$ and $sin$??

Comment: True enough. If you wish, you can write it as $-8(\cos 0 + i\sin 0)$, or $8(\cos\pi + i\sin\pi)$. Either of those is a valid polar form.

Comment: Distinction without a difference.

Comment: Wait. I understood you up to where you have $cos\frac{\pi}{4}$ How do you get $cos\pi$ from that?

Comment: In the first case you have $r=-8$; in the second, $r=8$ but $\cos\pi = -1$, so it comes to the same thing.

Comment: @rogerl The polar form requires the parameter $r$ to be non-negative.

Comment: And it really depends on exactly what your teacher is looking for. $-8$ is a perfectly valid description of the point, in either rectangular or polar coordinates.

Comment: @GitGud I don't really agree --- but I do agree that that is the usual convention. Wikipedia, for example, does not require it but does point out that if you do, you get uniqueness up to multiples of $2\pi$ for $\theta$.

Comment: @rogerl I don't know what you're reading. But the usual extrapolations of the concept require positivity. See [polar decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_decomposition) and [polar form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_number#Polar_form).

Comment: @GitGud I was reading [polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system).

Comment: @rogerl: the first sentence of your link refers to "distance" which is a positive quantity between distinct points.

Comment: -8 us what the number *is*, but it is not written in polar form, which would be $8 e^{i\pi}$. Similar to if you were asked to give a fraction in lowest form, you have to do it a certain way.

Comment: @LeeMosher Fair enough, although the paragraph labeled "Conventions" says otherwise. I'll modify the answer.

Comment: I still don't understand how the coefficient of i is zero?

Comment: The *value* of the expression is $-8$, and $-8$ lies on the real line embedded in the complex plane. So its imaginary part is zero. Was that your question?

Answer (score 2):

You can also convert numerator and denominator into polar form immediately to write

$$ \frac{ [ \ \sqrt{2} \ cis(\frac{\pi}{4}) \ ]^{13} \ }{[ \ \sqrt{2} \ cis(-\frac{\pi}{4}) \ ]^7} \ \ . $$

DeMoivre's Theorem for powers gives us

$$ = \  \frac{  (\sqrt{2})^{13} \ cis(\frac{13\pi}{4})   }{(\sqrt{2})^7 \ cis(-\frac{7\pi}{4})} \ \ . $$

Division of complex numbers in polar form then produces

$$ = \  \frac{  (\sqrt{2})^{13} \   }{(\sqrt{2})^7}  \  cis( \ \left[\frac{13\pi}{4} \right] \ - \ \left[-\frac{7\pi}{4} \right] \ ) \ \ . $$

You would simplify things from there. (Since the answer's already been posted, I'll finish this off:

$$ = \ 2^{6/2} \ cis \left( \frac{20 \pi}{4} \right) \ = \ 2^3 \ cis(5 \pi) \ = \ 8 \ cis \ \pi \ \ \text{or} \ \ -8 \ \ .  ) $$

Comment: (Slightly unrelated) I like $\mathrm{cis},$ pedagogically it just makes a lot of sense.

Comment: For some reason, many introductory texts don't use it, but most practitioners do.  It's just a pain to write the factor out "longhand" in calculations with more than one line [you _know_ the argument of both trig terms is _the same!_], especially in lecture, so I show it to students early on.  (Of course, exponential notation is even quicker, but complex exponentials don't generally get presented even through two years of calculus courses...)

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of: its just a pain to try explaining why $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i \sin \theta$ in a basic, introductory course in which the students have no analysis or knowledge of infinite summations under their belt. Better to just write $\mathrm{cis}\,\theta$ and be done with it.

Comment: DeMoivre's Theorem for powers. What is that?

Comment: I keep getting stuck at $8(cos\frac{\pi}{4} + isin\frac{\pi}{4})^{20}$ What to do next?

Comment: The theorem states that $ \ [r \ cis(\theta)]^n \ = \ r^n \ cis(n \ \cdot \ \theta) \ $ . So $ \ (cis \ \frac{\pi}{4})^{20} \ = \ (cis \ [20 \cdot \frac{\pi}{4}]) \ $ .